# How to remove programmatically multiple Firebase Database paths

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I need to remove multiple paths of a Firebase Realtime Database.

**Option 1 - CLI**

Using the CLI and calling a script (.sh) , how can I execute the following commands consecutively without the need to confirm each operation?

```
firebase database:remove /path1;
firebase database:remove /path2;
```

Executing it, the CLI asks me to confim each of them.

**Option 2 - firebase-tools**

```
    const client = require("firebase-tools");

    const pathToRemove

    client.database.remove(pathToRemove, {
        project: 'my-database',
    }).then(
        x => console.log(util.inspect(x))
    ).catch(
        e => console.log(util.inspect(e))
    );
```

This returns the following message: "'Missing required options (confirm) while running in non-interactive mode'".

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me your database structure and say me which paths you want to delete ?